# Getting error when trying to use ReactJS.Net server side rendering with EPiServer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, episerver

I am trying to set up server side rendering using ReactJS.Net in an EPiServer project. In order to do that I am using the provided ReactJS.Net Html extention to do my rendering, however, when I run my site

> **I get an error saying**: "ReactJS.NET has not been initialised correctly. Please ensure you have called services.AddReact() and app.UseReact() in your Startup.cs file."

If I swap from trying to use the server rendering extension to trying to render normally with React

> **I get a different error**: "TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type: React.Web.BabelHandler".

I think the root issue is that there is some difference in how an EPiServer project initializes things at start up vs a vanilla .Net MVC project, but I am unsure of what the difference is or how to work around it.

I am working with the React.Web.Mvc4 v4.0.0 nuget package, Episerver 11, and .Net Framework 4.6.2. I took the same component I'm trying to render and pasted it into a vanilla .Net MVC project with no EPiServer and it renders properly client side and server side using the extension, so the component is not the issue. I found something saying that this error is usually seen when React or ReactDOM is not exposed to the global scope so I set it up to ensure that my react component is being added to the global scope, but no luck there either.

Here is my ReactConfig:

```
public static void Configure()
{
    JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
    JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();

    ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
        .AddScript("~/Static/js/Components/PrimaryCallout.jsx");
}
```

Here is my component:

```
class PrimaryCallout extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            header: this.props.header,
            buttonText: this.props.buttonText,
            buttonLink: this.props.buttonLink
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="primary-callout-container">
                <h2 className="primary-callout-header">{this.state.header}</h2>
                <a href={this.state.buttonLink} className="primary-callout-link">
                    <button className="primary-callout-button">{this.state.buttonText}</button>
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to render my component:

```
@Html.React("PrimaryCallout", new
{
    header = Model.Header,
    buttonText = Model.CalloutLinkText,
    buttonLink = Url.ContentUrl(Model.CalloutLink)
})
```

Any and all help or insight is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an OWIN Startup class? If so, what does it look like? If you're not using a Startup class, you may want to initialize React.NET in an Episerver initialization module.

Comment: @TedNyberg I don't have an OWIN Startup class set up I'm currently calling ReactConfig.Configure() in my Global.asax. I can try moving it into an Epi initialization module though. That's a good thought thanks.

Comment: @TedNyberg No luck with the initialization module. It's hitting the error before it hits the break point in my initialization module. It looks like my Global.asax gets run, but the ReactConfig.Configure() call in there doesn't seem to be fixing the issue. I think the top level "ReactJS.NET has not been initialised correctly." error might just be smothering some other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging around I determined the issue I was having was indeed with Babel not with React. The React not initialized error was smothering the true issue. I didn't narrow it down to what in my Babel setup was wrong, but I re-did my bundling and minification setup and now I'm back up and running.

The lesson to take from this for anyone else is if you see this "ReactJS.NET has not been initialised correctly. Please ensure you have called services.AddReact() and app.UseReact() in your Startup.cs file." error then look deeper because it's likely smothering the error message for your true problem.

Comment: I am facing the same error message and opened an issue on https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/835
I have a MVC 4 project as well, using SSR and Webpack.
Could you share some of your files (webpack.config.js, ReactConfig.cs, Global.asax.cs, etc...) to try find the difference with mine ? thx